# How is "encrypted store" used in Android?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am following Google's IAP tutorial [Google In-app](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#Connect)

and it says :

> It is highly recommended that you do not hard-code the exact public license key string value as provided by Google Play. Instead, you can construct the whole public license key string at runtime from substrings, or retrieve it from an encrypted store, before passing it to the constructor.

How is "encrypted store" implemented to securely store a string ?
There doesn't seem to be a whole lot of information about it.

Comment: I guess this is just a generic term referring to some kind of encryption you could implement in the app.

Comment: Yeah I suppose so - I could find no demo/tutorial/example in regards to "encrypted store". I think that was "an easy way out" for the documentation dude at Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did to make it fun for a cracker:

**1)** I used JNI to hide a decryption key and I made sure that the resulting object file is bigger than 256KB by including data from random word generator and a cat picture. It's important to make the object file bigger than 256KB to prevent use of https://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/ To develop with the NDK, follow this tutorial http://ph0b.com/new-android-studio-ndk-support/

**2)** I hard-coded my encrypted Google Play billing license key in a java class, after splitting it up into several separate strings. (do not put this in /res/strings because it's too easy to find after disassembling the apk with "apktool", see https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/

**3)** This is the class I used to perform the encryption and decryption https://github.com/scottyab/AESCrypt-Android/blob/master/aescrypt/src/main/java/com/scottyab/aescrypt/AESCrypt.java

This took about 2 days to figure out and implement, so I wish Google would allow insertion of license keys at the "Generate Signed APK" stage, which my app (and only my app) could then read.

> If anyone has any other suggestions, please comment...

**NOTE:**
I wanted to go with the RSA encryption but I found that the billing license key is too large for RSA, hence, the use of AES.

Comment: So your whole app was using Android NDK?

Comment: no, not the whole app, just the part that reads the hidden keys

Comment: Can you post a code sample on Github Gist? I am trying to get In-App Billing  working on my app, and it would be a great help.